# Find polygons that contain at least one of a list of Points in Python

Tags: python, pandas, shapely, geopandas

I have two datasets, one is the shape file of the french regions, and the second is a file containing points. I want to (efficiently) find the regions containing at least one point. 
When I print the two datasets i see [image]

I have tried to read the shape files with geopandas as follows

```
point_data = gpd.read_file(name_file) # I read the points 
regions = gpd.read_file('regions-20180101-shp/regions-20180101.shp')  # I read the regions 
reg.apply(lambda x: x.geometry.contains(point_data).any()) # I try to get the intersectons
```

I get an error. While if I simply try 
`reg.geometry.contains(point_data)` 
I get

```
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
...
```

And I get the same results if I use `within`. Of course I can do it with for cycles but I would like to find a more efficient way.

Comment: Normally what you tried `reg.apply(lambda x: x.geometry.contains(point_data).any())` should be the way to go. What error did you get?

Comment: hi, I get this error 
AttributeError: ("'GeoSeries' object has no attribute '_geom'", u'occurred at index 0'). It seems he does not read the point_data as a geometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you tried was almost correct. When applying a function to a GeoSeries, the function receives single shapely geometries, so in this case a single polygon. For that single polygon, we want to check if at least one of the points is within that polygon:

```
regions.apply(lambda x: points.within(x).any())
```

With as small reproducible example:

```
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
regions = geopandas.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1, 0)]), 
                               Polygon([(1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (2, 1)]),
                               Polygon([(1,0), (1,1), (2,1), (2, 0)])])
points = geopandas.GeoSeries([Point(0.5, 0.5), Point(0.2, 0.8), Point(1.2, 1.8)])
```

which looks like:

[image]

then applying the function looks like:

```
>>> regions.apply(lambda x: points.within(x).any())
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

If `regions` and `points` would be GeoDataFrames instead of GeoSeries, you will need to add a `.geometry` in the above.

Comment: Thanks, regions and points were GeoDataFrames, and adding geometry it worked perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be given by the types being Points and not Polygons.

One way around I have found is to make the points as a polygon, and then study the intesection between polygons. In this case it works well, but this wont always give the correct answer. The code is

```
g1 = point_data.geometry
g1 = [list(g.coords)[0] for g in g1]
p1 = polygon.Polygon(g1)
reg.apply(lambda x: x.geometry.intersects(p1),axis=1)
```

Once again this will only work if the polygons with contain at least one point are neighbors.